# How to pass from controller to view using Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I read the sails documentation and apparently I am doing it correctly but I keep getting *undefined*.
My model:

```
module.exports = {
schema:true,
conection:'NodeSailsMsSql',
tableName:'contactos',
autoUpdatedAt: false,
autoCreatedAt:false,

attributes: {

nombre:{
  type:'string',
  required:true
},
telefonocel:{
  type:'int'
},
telefonocasa:{
  type:'int'
},
telefonotrabajo:{
  type:'int'
},
correo:{
  type:'string',
  email:true
},
idtipocontacto:{
  type:'integer',
  required:true
}

}
};
```

My Controller

```
agregar: function(req,res,next){
Contactos.create(req.allParams(),function contactosagregados(err, contactos) 
{
  if(err)return next(err);
  res.redirect('contactos/mostrarcontactos/'+contactos.id);
});
},
mostrarcontactos: function(req,res,next){
Contactos.query('select * from contactos where id='+('id'),function 
contactosencotrados(err, contactos) {
  if(err)return next(err);
  if(!contactos) return next();
  res.view({
    contacto:contactos
  });
});
},
```

View

```
<h1><%= contacto.id %></h1>
<hr>
<h3>Correo:<%= contacto.Correo %></h3>
<h3>Nombre: <%= contacto.Nombre %></h3>
```

If I debug the data is on the controller on contacto, but somehow the data is lost when passed to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you seem to be asking for records where the id is literally `'id'`. I think you must mean to get the id from the request somehow?  Maybe like this:

```
mostrarcontactos: function(req,res,next){
  var inputId = req.param('id');
  Contactos.query('select * from contactos where id=' + inputId, function contactosencotrados(err, contactos) {
    // you should check what your result looks like. With .query that depends on which database you are using
    sails.log(contactos);
    if(err) {return next(err);}
    if(!contactos) {return next();}
    res.view({
      contacto:contactos
    });
  });
```

},

Give that a try, and make sure the properties you are trying to access in the view match what is on the retrieved data `contactos`.

Comment: If i debug the info is under contacto on controller, but its undefined on the view

Comment: Do you mean `contactos` with an `s`? Because that is the callback argument returned from your query, and it is the value you give to `contacto` (no `s`) in the view.

Comment: yes, I am new to sails/nodejs, and I thougth the data on `contacto` was based on my model and not on MySql columns, for example, on my model i have `cellphone` but on MySql I have `CellPhone`, so I was triying to use `contacto.cellphone` on my view, when the correct way is `contacto.CellPhone`.

Comment: Gotcha. For the future, when you use `.find` or `.findOne`, etc, you get sails models, but `.query` sort of reveals the underlying database, so what you get depends on your db implementation.